# Undefined offset 1

Tags: php

I am facing a problem that undefined offset :1 in line 3. I can't understand that what type of error it is.
Can anyone tell me that why such error occurs in php

Undefined offset in line : 3

```
    foreach ($lines as $line)
    {
      list($var,$value) = explode('=', $line); //line 3
      $data[$var] = $value;
    }
```

Comment: What's the output of `print_r($lines);` before your loop ?

Comment: I am currently having this issue. I have the line: list($lastname, $firstname, $email, $city, $bYear) = explode('|', $line); and when I print_r I get the expected output to the screen but I still have the Undefined offset Notice. Any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your are getting PHP `notice` because you are trying to access an array index which is not set.

```
list($var,$value) = explode('=', $line);
```

The above line explodes the string `$line` with `=` and assign `0th` value in `$var` and `1st` value in `$value`. The issue arises when `$line` contains some string without `=`.

Comment: thanks for answer. The `print_r($lines)` shows me the last value without `=` . What is the way to overcome in this?

Comment: @tushAR: check whether the value has `=` before you do the `explode`

Answer (score 11):

I know this an old question and the answer provided is sufficient.

> Your are getting PHP notice because you are trying to access an array
>   index which is not set.

But I believe the best way to overcome the problem with undefined indexes when there are cases where you may have an empty array using the `list()`/`explode()` combo is to set default values using `array_pad()`.

The reason being is when you use `list()` you know the number of variables you want from the array.

For example:

```
$delim = '=';
$aArray = array()
$intNumberOfListItems = 2;


list($value1, $value2) = array_pad(explode($delim, $aArray, $intNumberOfListItems ), $intNumberOfListItems , null);
```

Essentially you pass a third parameter to explode stating how many values you need for your `list()` variables (in the above example two).  Then you use `array_pad()` to give a default value (in the above example null) when the array does not contain a value for the list variable.

Answer (score 3):

This is caused because your `$line` doesn't contain "`=`" anywhere in the string so it contains only one element in array.list() is used to assign a list of variables in one operation. Your list contains 2 elements but as from data returned by implode, there is only one data. So it throws a notice.
A way to overcome that is to use [array_pad()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php) method.

```
list($var,$value) = array_pad(explode('=', $line),2,null);
```

Answer (score 1):

by doing list($var, $value) php will expect an array of 2 elements, if the explode function doesn't find an equal symbol it will only return an array with 1 element causing the undefined offset error, offset 1 is the second element of an array so most likely one of your $line variables doesn't have an equal sign

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the array. The array index is not showing due to this undefine offset error will come...

So please check the array with print_r function.

Answer (score 1):

The `list` language construct is used to create individual variables from an array.  If your array doesn't have enough elements for the number of variables you are expecting in the `list` call, you will get an error.  In your case you have 2 variables so you need an array with 2 items - indexes 0 and 1.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
$lines = array('one' => 'fruit=apple', 'two' => 'color=red', 'three' => 'language');

foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    list($var,$value) = (strstr($line, '=') ? explode('=', $line) : array($line, ''));
    $data[$var] = $value;
}

print_r($data);
```

Try this one..

For reference
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php